# Node publishes to a topic but subscriber does not react

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot with a gazebo_ros_control plugin. So there is a  `robot/joint_drive_wheel/command` topic to which you publish commands for velocity.

I have also written an rqt plugin that publishes to the topic and ros node that publishes to the topic.

When I use terminal command `rostopic pub robot/joint_right_wheel_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: 5.0"`, the robot reacts.

When I use the rqt plugin, the robot reacts.

When I use the ros node, however, the robot reacts only to commands published in a callback function of a subscriber to different topic. When I want to command the velocity in after creating the publisher, the command does get to the topic (I watch with `rostopic echo`), but the robot doesn't react to the command.

This is my node:

```
import rospy
import rospkg
from std_msgs.msg import Bool
from std_msgs.msg import Float64

import time

def callback(data):
    _robot_stop()
    _robot_backup()
    _robot_turn90right()
    _robot_forward()


def _robot_stop():
    publisher_dict['right'].publish(0.0)
    publisher_dict['left'].publish(0.0)

def _robot_backup():
    publisher_dict['right'].publish(-5.0)
    publisher_dict['left'].publish(-5.0)
    time.sleep(1)
    _robot_stop()

def _robot_turn90right():
    publisher_dict['right'].publish(-5.0)
    publisher_dict['left'].publish(5.0)
    time.sleep(1)
    _robot_stop()  

def _robot_turn90left():
    publisher_dict['right'].publish(5.0)
    publisher_dict['left'].publish(-5.0)
    time.sleep(1)
    _robot_stop()  

def _robot_forward():
    publisher_dict['right'].publish(5.0)
    publisher_dict['left'].publish(5.0)

def mynode():

    rospy.init_node('mynode')

    publisher_dict['right'] = rospy.Publisher('/robot/joint_right_wheel_controller/command', Float64, queue_size=1)
    publisher_dict['left'] = rospy.Publisher('/robot/joint_left_wheel_controller/command', Float64, queue_size=1)

    rospy.Subscriber("/robot/another_topic", Bool, callback)

    _robot_forward()

    rospy.spin()


publisher_dict = { } 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        mynode()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Once I run the node (when the simulation is running), I would expect the robot to move forward, because of the command `_robot_forward()` right before the  `rospy.spin()`. And the command does appears at the topic when I listen to it via terminal. But the robot does not move. I'm confused. Why might that be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306425/node-publishes-to-a-topic-but-subscriber-does-not-react/) by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 308 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These connections take a little bit to be set up. I would try 2 things

1. set up publisher, then sleep for half a second or something, then subscribe and run
2. set up publisher, set up subscriber, sleep for half a second, then run

Assuming either of those makes it work, it should prompt you down the right road.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2018-10-23**:
Thank you. I tried to put sleep before the robot command before, but I guess it slept for too little or it really makes difference that it sleeps in between commands setting the publisher and subscriber. This advice solved the issue.

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2018-10-23**:
Though I still wonder. How comes the message is being published to the topic (seen through `rostopic echo /robot/joint_controller/command`) but the robot doesn't react to it, if the controller manager is already running? What am I missing?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-10-23**:
It takes a little bit for the ROS master to register the subs and have all the connections drawn. This is a major reason to create all your sub/pubs in a constructor before use so that they're all initialized.